# Runtime Error & Time Complexity Issues: Minimize the value |(A[0] + ... + A[P-1]) - (A[P] + ... + A[N-1])|

Tags: javascript, big-o, time-complexity, array-algorithms

I recently tackled a coding problem.  I came up with a solution to the following problem.

> A non-empty zero-indexed array A consisting of N integers is given. Array A represents numbers on a tape.
>   Any integer P, such that 0 < P < N, splits this tape into two non-empty parts: A[0], A[1], ..., A[P − 1] and A[P], A[P + 1], ..., A[N − 1].
>   The difference between the two parts is the value of: |(A[0] + A[1] + ... + A[P − 1]) − (A[P] + A[P + 1] + ... + A[N − 1])|
>   In other words, it is the absolute difference between the sum of the first part and the sum of the second part.
>   For example, consider array A such that:
>     A[0] = 3
>     A[1] = 1
>     A[2] = 2
>     A[3] = 4
>     A[4] = 3
>   We can split this tape in four places:
>   P = 1, difference = |3 − 10| = 7 
>   P = 2, difference = |4 − 9| = 5 
>   P = 3, difference = |6 − 7| = 1 
>   P = 4, difference = |10 − 3| = 7 
>   
>   Write a function:
>   function solution(A);
>   that, given a non-empty zero-indexed array A of N integers, returns the minimal difference that can be achieved.
>   For example, given:
>     A[0] = 3
>     A[1] = 1
>     A[2] = 2
>     A[3] = 4
>     A[4] = 3
>   the function should return 1, as explained above.
>   Assume that:
>   N is an integer within the range [2..100,000];
>   each element of array A is an integer within the range [−1,000..1,000].
>   
>   Complexity:
>   expected worst-case time complexity is O(N);
>   expected worst-case space complexity is O(N), beyond input storage (not counting the storage required for input arguments).
>   Elements of input arrays can be modified.

The following is the feedback I obtained from testing the solution:

> CORRECTNESS:
>   small_range  range sequence, length = ~1,000  1.900 s 
> RUNTIME ERROR 
>   tested program terminated unexpectedly
>   PERFORMANCE:
>   Detected time complexity: O(N * N)

So I am getting one runtime error for ranges around 1000.  And most importantly, I am not getting O(n).  I am getting O(n * n) as I am using nested for loops.

(1) How could I fix the runtime error?
(2) How could one construct O(n) algorithm for the same problem?  Any suggestions?

This is my solution:

```
    function solution(A){
        var len = A.length;
        var diff = [];  // Array to store the differences
        var sumLeft = 0;    // Sum of array elements from index 0 to index p - 1
        var sumRight = 0;   // Sum of array elements from index p to index n - 1
        for(var p = 1; p < len; p++){
            sumLeft = 0;
            sumRight = 0;
            // Calculate sumLeft:
            for(var i = 0; i < p; i++){
                sumLeft += A[i];
            }
            // Calculate sumRight:
            for(var j = p; j < len; j++){
                sumRight += A[j];
            }
            // Calculate differences, compute absolute values, and push into diff array:
            diff.push(Math.abs(sumLeft - sumRight));
        }
        // Return the minimum of diff array by sorting it and returning the first element:
        return bubbleSort(diff)[0];
    }

    function bubbleSort(array){
        var len = array.length;
        for(var i = 0; i < len; i++){
            for(var j = i + 1; j < len; j++){
                if(array[i] > array[j]){
                    var temp = array[i];
                    array[i] = array[j];
                    array[j] = temp;
                }
            }
        }
        return array;
    }
```

Comment: Thank you all very much for providing your insights.  I feel that after this discussion I have become a more mature and cautious programmer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let me try to explain you how you can think about improving the space and time complexity of your algorithm. You realize where clearly that you're using nested for loops and it greatly increases the iterations and might also be causing the run-time error for sufficiently large inputs.

The first step should be reducing the redundancy of your operations. Now you calculate the `left` and `right` sums repeatedly for different values of `p`. You don't need that at all. I'll give you an example for how the algorithm will flow:

```
 Array indices -> A [0, 1, 2, 3, ....,p ,p+1, ....n-1] for a size n array

 At any point A[p] would act as a pivot as it breaks the array into two.
 For p = 1, You just take the first element i.e A[0] and the right part of the sum is
 A[1] + A[2] + .... A[n-1]

 Let S1 = A[0] and S2 = A[1] + A[2] + .... A[n-1] for p = 1
 The pivot or the break point here is A[p] i.e A[1]

 Calculate the absolute difference |S1- S2| and store it in a variable min-diff

 For p = 2, 

 S1 will simply be S1 + A[1] i.e the previous value of S1 including the last pivot 

 S2 = S2 - A[1], as we have moved on to the next element. 
 The sum of the remaining elements would not account the element we just crossed.

Formally,

S1 = S1 + A[p-1] and S2 = S2 - A[p-1]

Calculate the new difference i.e |S1 - S2| and just check 
if it is smaller than the value of our variable min-diff. 
If it is, update the value of min-diff with the present difference, 
otherwise move on to the next element.

At any value of p, S1 represents sum of left half, 
S2 represents sum of right half and 
min-diff represents the minium absolute difference till now.
```

### Complexity for this algorithm

1. **Time complexity**

   The only time we calculate the sum of the elements is the first time
   when we calculate A[1]+...A[n-1]. After that we just traverse the
   elements of the array one by one.

   So we traverse the elements of the array at max twice. So time
   complexity is clearly **O(N)**
2. **Space complexity**

   We use three extra variables i.e S1, S2 and min-diff all through
   this algorithm to accumulate the sum and store the minimum absolute
   difference along with the value of p and the n elements of the
   array.

   So space complexity of this algorithm is again **O(N)**

On a side note- Although you don't require sorting for this problem at all since you're to output the minimum difference only, but whenever sorting, please don't use bubble-sort at it is clearly the least efficient sorting method. You're better off with merge sort or quick sort which have a run time of **O(NlogN)**

I hope I was able to explain myself. Try to code this into a simple function, shouldn't take long. It should probably fix the run-time error as well.

Comment: Given the nature of the `abs` function, you will only need to iterate till the difference between the right part and the left part starts increasing. If that happens, you have hit the minimum, and it is sub-optimal to proceed through the whole array.

Comment: @Achrome, in the question he mentions that the values of the array could be negative or positive. I don't know if I can explain if there will be a trend in the absolute minimum difference of the left and right half sums in this case. I would appreciate if you could elaborate on this further.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to calculate the sum of the vector pieces when you test a new value of `P`. If you calculated `leftSum` and `rightSum` for both parts for `P=(p-1)`, when you have to calculate it for `P=p` you just need to:

- Remove `array[p]` from `rightSum`; and
- Add  `array[p]` to `leftSum`.

This both are O(1). If you do it (n-1) times, you are still under O(n) complexity.

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

Code with java : O(N)

```
import java.math.*;

class Solution {

  public int solution(int[] A) {

    long sumright = 0;
    long sumleft = 0;
    long ans;

    for (int i =1;i<A.length;i++)
    {
      sumright += A[i];
    }

    sumleft = A[0];
    ans =Math.abs(sumright+sumleft);

    for (int P=1; P<A.length; P++)
    {
      if (Math.abs(sumleft - sumright)<ans)
      {
        ans = Math.abs(sumleft - sumright);
      }
      sumleft += A[P];
      sumright -=A[P];
    }
  return (int) ans;
}
```

}

Comment: This only gets a 71% correctness score on Codility. It doesn't work if there are only two elements (`[-1000, 1000]`) and the small test desn't work.

Comment: `ans =Math.abs(sumright+sumleft);` should be rewritten as ans = `Math.abs(sumright-sumleft)`;

I'll post my solution.

Answer (score 0):

Without debugging, this solution gets a 100% task score on Codility (with 100% for both correctness and performance):

```
function solution(A) {
    var sum_right = 0;

    for (int of A.slice(1)) {
        sum_right += int;
    }

    var sum_left = A[0];
    var diff_of_sums = sum_left - sum_right;
    var lowest_diff = Math.abs(diff_of_sums);
    var diff_new;
    // we assume the length is at least 2
    if (A.length == 2) {
        return lowest_diff;
    }
    for (var int of A.slice(1)) {
        diff_new = Math.abs(sum_left - sum_right);
        if (diff_new < lowest_diff) {
            lowest_diff = diff_new;
        }
        sum_left += int;
        sum_right -= int;
    }
    return lowest_diff;
}
```

With debugging:

```
// you can write to stdout for debugging purposes, e.g.
// console.log('this is a debug message');

function solution(A) {
    var sum_right = 0;

    for (int of A.slice(1)) {
        sum_right += int;
    }

    var sum_left = A[0];
    var diff_of_sums = sum_left - sum_right;
    // var total = Math.abs(sum_left + sum_right);
    var lowest_diff = Math.abs(diff_of_sums);
    var diff_new;
    // we assume the length is at least 2
    if (A.length == 2) {
        return lowest_diff;
    }
    // console.log("lowest_diff initially:", lowest_diff)
    // var diff_of_sums_new = diff_of_sums;
    // console.log("diff_of_sums initially:", diff_of_sums)
    // console.log("A.slice(1):", A.slice(1))
    for (var int of A.slice(1)) {
        // console.log("lowest_diff", lowest_diff)
        diff_new = Math.abs(sum_left - sum_right);
        if (diff_new < lowest_diff) {
            lowest_diff = diff_new;
        }
        sum_left += int;
        sum_right -= int;
    }
    //           if (Math.abs(sumleft - sumright)<ans)
    //   {
    //     ans = Math.abs(sumleft - sumright);
    //   }
    //   sumleft += A[P];
    //   sumright -=A[P];
    //     // console.log("int === -1:", int === -1);
    //     // diff_of_sums = diff_of_sums_new;
    //     console.log("lowest_diff =", lowest_diff);
    //     // console.log("A[index + 1] =", A[parseInt(index) + 1]);
    //     // console.log("parseInt(index) === 1", parseInt(index) === 1)
    //     diff_of_sums = Math.abs(lowest_diff - 2 * Math.abs(int));
    //     // console.log("diff_of_sums =", diff_of_sums);
    //     // console.log("diff_of_sums = Math.abs(diff_of_sums - 2 * A[index + 1]) = ", diff_of_sums_new);
    //     if (diff_of_sums < lowest_diff) {
    //         lowest_diff = diff_of_sums;
    //         // console.log("lowest_diff = diff_of_sums =", diff_of_sums_new)
    //     } else {
    //         return lowest_diff;
    //     }
    // }
    // console.log("lowest_diff before returning", lowest_diff);
    return lowest_diff;
}
// Note that it's better to use test cases in Codility for this, but I've left here to show some.
// console.log("solution([-1000, 1000])", solution([-1000, 1000]));
// console.log("solution([2, 7, 20, 30, 1])", solution([2, 7, 20, 30, 1])); // sum 60, smallest diff = |29 - 31| = 2
// console.log("solution([-2, -7, -20, -30, -1])", solution([-2, -7, -20, -30, -1])); // sum -60, smallest diff = 2
// console.log("solution([-1, -1]):", solution([-1, -1]));
// console.log("solution([-2, -1]):", solution([-2, -1]));
// console.log("solution([-2, -1, -3]):", solution([-2, -1, -3]));
// console.log("solution([]):", solution([]))
```

Initially I tried starting from halfway, but this made the implementation more complicated. This is what I came up with before I ditched that approach (and I can't be bothered with hacking on a solution):

```
function solution(A) {
    // const sum = A.reduce((partial_sum, a) => partial_sum + a); 
    // console.log(sum);
    var size = A.length;
    if (size % 2 == 0) {
        mid = size/2;
    } else {
        mid = Math.floor(size/2);
    }
    console.log("mid initially", mid);
    var sum1 = A.slice(0, mid).reduce((partial_sum, a) => partial_sum + a);
    // console.log("sum1:",sum1);
    var sum2 = A.slice(mid).reduce((partial_sum, a) => partial_sum + a);
    // console.log("sum2:", sum2);
    var sum_diff = sum1 - sum2;
    // console.log("sum_diff:", sum_diff);
    if (sum_diff === 0) {
        return sum_diff;
    }
    // sum_diff = function() {Math.abs(sum2 - sum1)};
    // sum_diff = sum_diff();
    var lowest_diff = Math.abs(sum_diff);
    var diff_negative = (sum_diff < 0);
    console.log("diff_negative initially:", diff_negative)
    var crossed_over = false;
    var sum_diff_new;
    while (diff_negative) {
        mid++;
        if (mid === size) {
            return lowest_diff;
        }
        // var sum1_new = sum1 + A[mid];
        // var sum2_new = sum2 - A[mid];
        // sum_diff_new = sum1_new - sum2_new = sum1 - sum2 + 2*A[mid] = sum_diff - 2*A[mid];
        sum_diff_new = sum_diff - 2*A[mid];
        diff_negative = (sum_diff_new < 0);
        if (diff_negative = false) {
            crossed_over = true;
            if (lowest_diff <= sum_diff_new) {
                return lowest_diff;
            } else {
                return sum_diff_new;
            }
        }
    }

    while(!diff_negative) {
        mid--;
        if (mid === -1) {
            return lowest_diff;
        }
        // var sum1_new = sum1 - A[mid];
        // var sum2_new = sum2 + A[mid];
        // sum_diff_new = sum1_new - sum2_new = sum1 - sum2 - 2*A[mid] = sum_diff - 2*A[mid];
        console.log("sum_diff:", sum_diff);
        sum_diff_new = sum_diff + 2*A[mid];
        console.log("sum_diff_new:", sum_diff_new);
        diff_negative = (sum_diff_new < 0);
        if (diff_negative = true) {
            crossed_over = true;
            var sum_diff_new_pos = Math.abs(sum_diff_new);
            if (lowest_diff <= sum_diff_new_pos) {
                return lowest_diff;
            } else {
                return sum_diff_new_pos;
            }
        }
    }
}

// Issues: doesn't work e.g. with  [-2, -1, -3] and [-2, -7, -20, -30, -1]
```